# Is there an episode where the sisters go back in time, and for a spell, it's implied they bought future illegal drugs?

Tags: episode-identification, charmed

Is there an episode where the sisters go back in time, and for a spell, it's implied they bought future illegal drugs?

I remember a line like "this would have been illegal back in our time", or something else with the word "illegal" in it.

But looking through transcripts of time travel episodes, I can't find it.

I think they bought it at an apothecary, but searching transcripts for the medieval time travel episodes for "apothecary" doesn't bring any lines that fit what I remember, although I'm not sure I read all the episodes.

And then there's how "apothecary" seems to have been only used [in two](https://charmed.fandom.com/wiki/Special:Search?query=apothecary&scope=internal&navigationSearch=true) episodes and neither are used for a medieval potion ingredients shop.

Comment: https://charmed.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Travel

Comment: Is this in the original series, or the remake?

Comment: @FlaStorm32 - Original.

Answer (score 3):

It could possibly be Witchstock, S06E11.  In it, Grams's go-go boots transport Paige to 1967.  When Penny (the young Grams) mentions a "magical be-in," Paige connects it to the "Human Be-in" (a real event in 1967 San Francisco) and Timothy Leary and his pro-LSD advocacy.  Penny quickly admonishes Paige that there's "no acid allowed" in the house, although they are on a "contact high."  Later on, the sisters do discuss making a potion, but not specifically where they will get the ingredients or what they are.

Comment: Whoops... I see what you mean, but nope, quite sure that's not it. Adding more refinement to the question.